# Algebra behind MVRNorm in MASS package

Tags: r

Here's the code:

```
function (n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-06, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE) 
{
    p <- length(mu)
    if (!all(dim(Sigma) == c(p, p))) 
        stop("incompatible arguments")
    if (EISPACK) 
        stop("'EISPACK' is no longer supported by R", domain = NA)
    eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
    ev <- eS$values
    if (!all(ev >= -tol * abs(ev[1L]))) 
        stop("'Sigma' is not positive definite")
    X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n)
    if (empirical) {
        X <- scale(X, TRUE, FALSE)
        X <- X %*% svd(X, nu = 0)$v
        X <- scale(X, FALSE, TRUE)
    }
    X <- drop(mu) + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), p) %*% 
        t(X)
    nm <- names(mu)
    if (is.null(nm) && !is.null(dn <- dimnames(Sigma))) 
        nm <- dn[[1L]]
    dimnames(X) <- list(nm, NULL)
    if (n == 1) 
        drop(X)
    else t(X)
}
```

The line in question I am curious about is this:

```
 x <- eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(ev)) %*% t(x) # ignoring drop(mu)
 ...
 t(x)
```

Why is it that

X^T = UVZ^T, where Z is a standardized MVN?

I had thought that this would be X = UVZ, where X ~ MVN(0, UV(I)(UV)^T) = MVN(0, Sigma)?

In response to Siong Thye Goh's answer:

I can see the algebra, and that it does work only doing it this way by just considering the dimensions, but the whole act of transposing everything seems strange to do considering the properties of a multivariate normal.  That is, X = UVZ

I did some reviewing and I found that this is actually a [Matrix Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution), and the affine transformation there works in the similar fashion.  That is, X = Z (UV)^T.

I'm not sure if there is just something silly I'm missing in understanding this or if I'm missing the picture altogether on why everything is transposed in regards to, say, [Wikipedias Affine Transformation of a MVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

U is the eigenvector of Sigma. That is Sigma = UV^2 U^T, where V is a diagonal matrix.

Let's compute the covariance matrix E[X^TX] and see if it is equal to Sigma where X=UVZ^T and Z^T satisfy E[Z^TZ]=I, the identity matrix.

We have

E[X^TX]=E[UVZ^TZVU^T]=UVE[Z^TZ]VU^T=UV^2U^T=Sigma

Comment: We are used to eigenvectors being columns. However in programming, we want each row to be a sample, hence we tranpose it.